# Auto load as soon as the flask server starts

Tags: tensorflow, flask

I'm building a web for image detection, and I want to load and start pb data as soon as I start the server. This is because the cache makes detection faster.

Is there a good way?

```
output_detect = tf_module.detect(image)
```

Currently tf_module is run after the image is uploaded.
Can I run a module without uploading an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is to implement before first request decorator. Functions decorated with @app.before_first_request will run once before the first request to this instance of the application. You could trigger this first request yourself after starting the server. Small example:

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request_func():
    print("This function runs once")
```